# Question about Optical tweezers working principle

Tags: visible-light, electric-fields, laser, polarization, dipole

Why do particles on the periphery of the laser beam in optical tweezers apparatus drift to the center of the beam? What force pattern causes this pull to the center?

Comment: @Emilio Pisant there you go. if you have an an answer you can answer it here.

Comment: Note that [`@` replies only work in limited circumstances](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). (I'm seeing this as you post it out of pure coincidence.)

Comment: Yes, I figured it. But wasn't sure if there is an alternative to @ that I could use.

Comment: There isn't, by design. If you're asking a relevant follow-up to a previous answer, it is OK to post a link below it. Otherwise, you shouldn't ping individual users - there's a large population of people who can provide answers, and it's a mistake to rely on any single user to do so.

Comment: Sure, I gotcha!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It depends on the nature of the particle, whether it will experience a force in an optical field. In many of the experiments that demonstrate these effects people use little dielectric balls made from material with a higher refractive index than that of the liquid in which they are suspended. Moreover, these ball are usually suspended in a thin layer of fluid that allows these little balls to move in a two-dimensional ($x,y$) plane that is perpendicular to the general propagation directon ($z$-direction) of the optical beam.

The force that the ball would experience is cause by a gradient in the intensity profile of the optical beam. It is simple an effect of the refraction. Light that enters a ball is now refracted toward the opposite side. Due to the change in momentum the ball must pick up the difference in momentum.

So, image there is a line along the $z$-direction drawn through the center of the ball. If a light-ray, propagating in the $z$-direction parallel to this line, enters the ball on the left-hand side (right-hand side) of the line, then the ball will bend that light ray toward the right-hand side (left-hand side). So if the light on one side is brighter that the light on the other side (due to a gradient in the intensity) the ball will feel a net force toward the brighter part of the optical beam.

Hope my explanation is comprehencible.

Comment: This is a reasonable explanation (explained in more depth (or at least with diagrams) in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_tweezers#Ray_optics)) but it's important to note that it is only valid if the particles are much larger than the wavelength of the light, and that is still perfectly possible to trap smaller particles to which this explanation does not apply.

Comment: How important is it for the balls you've mentioned above to be dielectric?

Comment: Well the mechanism works with the difference in the refractive index. If the particle is made of metal, for instance, it would not work. Or at least it would require a different mechanism.

Answer (score -1):

First the laser beam should be highly focused and with a high numerical aperture. Due to the electromagnetic forces of the light beam, the particle experiences a change of momentum, such creating the gradient force and the scattering force on the surface of the particle. Combining different variables such as power of the laser, the numerical aperture, the refractive index of the particle, the shape of the particle, leads to the right equilibrium of this forces, meaning gradient  force bigger than scattering force, thus pushing the particle in the center, where the well of potential energy is created.